# textbox is empty but still showing the count

Tags: asp.net

I have `textbox1` field in asp.net and a text area to show count of records.
 I want to count the records split by , in `textbox1`  but when `textbox1` is empty text area is showing 1.

Here is the code.

```
int contacts = textbox1.Text.Split(',').Count();
textarea.Text = contacts.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Split` always returns at least one string, if you pass `string.Empty` you will get one string which *is* the input string(so in this case `string.Empty`).

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ....
>   If this instance **does not contain any of the characters in separator, 
>   the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance**.

You have to check it, f.e. with `string.IsNullOrEmpty`(or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`):

```
int contacts = 0;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
    contacts = textbox1.Text.Split(',').Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int contacts = string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.textbox1.Text)? string.empty: textbox1.Text.Split(',').Count();
        textarea.Text = contacts.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because even when textbox1.Text is an empty string, that's still treated as one item. You need to use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) so that empty entries are ignored when producing the result of calling `Split`:

```
var contacts = textbox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Count();
```

To decompose what you've written into individual statements, what you have is:

```
var items = textbox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ', ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var countOfItems = itemsFromText.Count();
```

If you look at `items` you'll see that it's an array of strings (`string[]`) which contains one entry for each item in the text from `textbox1.Text`.

Even if an empty string is passed in (i.e. `textbox1` is empty) there's still *one* string to be returned, hence the fact that your code as written is returning *1*, whereas in `countOfItems` where I've broken the code apart it will have *0* because of the use of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

The documentation on msdn of the [String.Split overload that takes `StringSplitOptions` as a parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) has more examples and detail about this.

Comment: I uses the above mentioned techniques now it is showing me 1+ of original records. e.g if have count of records 11 then it is showing me 12 records

Comment: What string that contains 11 records is giving a `Count` of 12? That shouldn't be possible! =)